# dealing with IO vs pure code in haskell

Tags: haskell, io

I'm writing a shell script (my 1st non-example in haskell) which is supposed to list a directory, get every file size, do some string manipulation (pure code) and then rename some files. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong, so 2 questions:

1. How should i arrange the code in such program?
2. I have a specific issue, i get the following error, what am i doing wrong?

```
error:
    Couldn't match expected type `[FilePath]'
           against inferred type `IO [FilePath]'
    In the second argument of `mapM', namely `fileNames'
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression:
        files <- (mapM getFileNameAndSize fileNames)
    In the expression:
        do { fileNames <- getDirectoryContents;
             files <- (mapM getFileNameAndSize fileNames);
             sortBy cmpFilesBySize files }
```

code:

```
getFileNameAndSize fname = do (fname,  (withFile fname ReadMode hFileSize))

getFilesWithSizes = do
  fileNames <- getDirectoryContents
  files <- (mapM getFileNameAndSize fileNames)
  sortBy cmpFilesBySize files
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your second, specific, problem is with the types of your functions.  However, your first issue (not really a type thing) is the `do` statement in `getFileNameAndSize`.  While `do` is used with monads, it's not a monadic panacea; it's actually implemented as [some simple translation rules](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monads.html#monads.do).  The Cliff's Notes version (which isn't *exactly* right, thanks to some details involving error handling, but is close enough) is:

1. `do a` ≡ `a`
2. `do a ; b ; c ...` ≡ `a >> do b ; c ...`
3. `do x <- a ; b ; c ...` ≡ `a >>= \x -> do b ; c ...`

In other words, `getFileNameAndSize` is equivalent to the version without the `do` block, and so you can get rid of the `do`.  This leaves you with

```
getFileNameAndSize fname = (fname, withFile fname ReadMode hFileSize)
```

We can find the type for this: since `fname` is the first argument to `withFile`, it has type `FilePath`; and `hFileSize` returns an `IO Integer`, so that's the type of `withFile ...`.  Thus, we have `getFileNameAndSize :: FilePath -> (FilePath, IO Integer)`.  This may or may not be what you want; you might instead want `FilePath -> IO (FilePath,Integer)`.  To change it, you can write any of

```
getFileNameAndSize_do    fname = do size <- withFile fname ReadMode hFileSize
                                    return (fname, size)
getFileNameAndSize_fmap  fname = fmap ((,) fname) $
                                      withFile fname ReadMode hFileSize
-- With `import Control.Applicative ((<$>))`, which is a synonym for fmap.
getFileNameAndSize_fmap2 fname =     ((,) fname)
                                 <$> withFile fname ReadMode hFileSize
-- With {-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-} at the top of the file
getFileNameAndSize_ts    fname = (fname,) <$> withFile fname ReadMode hFileSize
```

Next, as KennyTM pointed out, you have `fileNames <- getDirectoryContents`; since `getDirectoryContents` has type `FilePath -> IO FilePath`, you need to give it an argument.  (*e.g.* `getFilesWithSizes dir = do fileNames <- getDirectoryContents dir ...`).  This is probably just a simple oversight.

Mext, we come to the heart of your error: `files <- (mapM getFileNameAndSize fileNames)`.  I'm not sure why it gives you the precise error it does, but I can tell you what's wrong.  Remember what we know about `getFileNameAndSize`.  In your code, it returns a `(FilePath, IO Integer)`.  However, `mapM` is of type `Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]`, and so `mapM getFileNameAndSize` is ill-typed.  You want `getFileNameAndSize :: FilePath -> IO (FilePath,Integer)`, like I implemented above.

Finally, we need to fix your last line.  First of all, although you don't give it to us, `cmpFilesBySize` is presumably a function of type `(FilePath, Integer) -> (FilePath, Integer) -> Ordering`, comparing on the second element.  This is really simple, though: using `Data.Ord.comparing :: Ord a => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Ordering`, you can write this `comparing snd`, which has type `Ord b => (a, b) -> (a, b) -> Ordering`.  Second, you need to return your result wrapped up in the IO monad rather than just as a plain list; the function `return :: Monad m => a -> m a` will do the trick.

Thus, putting this all together, you'll get

```
import System.IO           (FilePath, withFile, IOMode(ReadMode), hFileSize)
import System.Directory    (getDirectoryContents)
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Data.List           (sortBy)
import Data.Ord            (comparing)

getFileNameAndSize :: FilePath -> IO (FilePath, Integer)
getFileNameAndSize fname = ((,) fname) <$> withFile fname ReadMode hFileSize

getFilesWithSizes :: FilePath -> IO [(FilePath,Integer)]
getFilesWithSizes dir = do fileNames <- getDirectoryContents dir
                           files     <- mapM getFileNameAndSize fileNames
                           return $ sortBy (comparing snd) files
```

This is all well and good, and will work fine.  However, I *might* write it slightly differently.  My version would probably look like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
import System.IO           (FilePath, withFile, IOMode(ReadMode), hFileSize)
import System.Directory    (getDirectoryContents)
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Control.Monad       ((<=<))
import Data.List           (sortBy)
import Data.Ord            (comparing)

preservingF :: Functor f => (a -> f b) -> a -> f (a,b)
preservingF f x = (x,) <$> f x
-- Or liftM2 (<$>) (,), but I am not entirely sure why.

fileSize :: FilePath -> IO Integer
fileSize fname = withFile fname ReadMode hFileSize

getFilesWithSizes :: FilePath -> IO [(FilePath,Integer)]
getFilesWithSizes = return .   sortBy (comparing snd)
                           <=< mapM (preservingF fileSize)
                           <=< getDirectoryContents
```

([`<=<`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Control-Monad.html#v:%3C=%3C) is the monadic equivalent of `.`, the function composition operator.) First off: yes, my version is longer.  However, I'd probably already have `preservingF` defined somewhere, making the two equivalent in length.*  (I might even inline `fileSize` if it weren't used elsewhere.)  Second, I like this version better because it involves chaining together simpler pure functions we've already written.  While your version is similar, mine (I feel) is more streamlined and makes this aspect of things clearer.

So this is a bit of an answer to your first question of how to structure these things.  I personally tend to lock my IO down into as few functions as possible—only functions which need to touch the outside world directly (*e.g.* `main` and anything which interacts with a file) get an `IO`.  Everything else is an ordinary pure function (and is only monadic if it's monadic for general reasons, along the lines of `preservingF`).  I then arrange things so that `main`, etc., are just compositions and chains of pure functions: `main` gets some values from `IO`-land; then it calls pure functions to fold, spindle, and mutilate the date; then it gets more `IO` values; then it operates more; etc.  The idea is to separate the two domains as much as possible, so that the more compositional non-`IO` code is always free, and the black-box `IO` is only done precisely where necessary.

Operators like `<=<` really help with writing code in this style, as they let you operate on *functions* which interact with monadic values (such as the `IO`-world) just as you would operate on normal functions.  You should also look at [Control.Applicative's](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Control-Applicative.html) `function <$> liftedArg1 <*> liftedArg2 <*> ...` notation, which lets you apply ordinary functions to any number of monadic (really `Applicative`) arguments.  This is really nice for getting rid of spurious `<-`s and just chaining pure functions over monadic code.

*: I feel like `preservingF`, or at least its sibling `preserving :: (a -> b) -> a -> (a,b)`, should be in a package somewhere, but I've been unable to find either.

Comment: Thanks, great answer, i still understand very little i guess because i understand 40% of it, but it solved the problem ;)

Comment: Glad I could help.  Is there anything in particular you don't get?  A lot of stuff towards the end is more something I think you might want to look at/learn, rather than as something I think you ought to already know.

Answer (score 10):

[`getDirectoryContents` is a function](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/directory-1.0.1.1/System-Directory.html#v%3AgetDirectoryContents). You should supply an argument to it, e.g.

```
fileNames <- getDirectoryContents "/usr/bin"
```

---

Also, the type of `getFileNameAndSize` is `FilePath -> (FilePath, IO Integer)`, as you can check from ghci:

```
Prelude> :m + System.IO
Prelude System.IO> let getFileNameAndSize fname = do (fname, (withFile fname ReadMode hFileSize))
Prelude System.IO> :t getFileNameAndSize
getFileNameAndSize :: FilePath -> (FilePath, IO Integer)
```

But [`mapM` requires the input function to return an `IO stuff`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Control-Monad.html#v%3AmapM):

```
Prelude System.IO> :t mapM
mapM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
-- #                  ^^^^^^^^
```

You should change its type to `FilePath -> IO (FilePath, Integer)` to match the type.

```
getFileNameAndSize fname = do
  fsize <- withFile fname ReadMode hFileSize
  return (fname, fsize)
```