# Graph of a partial function in Haskell: a -> Maybe b -> [a] -> [(a, b)]

Tags: haskell, tuples, option-type

Given a partial function `f` and a list of arguments `xs`, I'm looking for the list of pairs `(x, f(x))` where `f` is defined. This seems like a natural thing to do, but so far I've failed to express it elegantly. I wonder if there's anything in the Maybe/Monad/Applicative/... area that can help? The following works, but it seems a little explicit.

```
import Data.Maybe (mapMaybe)

graph :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [(a, b)]
graph f = map (\x -> (x, f x))

liftMaybe :: (a, Maybe b) -> Maybe (a, b)
liftMaybe (x, Just y)  = Just (x, y)
liftMaybe (_, Nothing) = Nothing

partialgraph :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [(a, b)]
partialgraph f = mapMaybe liftMaybe . graph f
```

Does `liftMaybe` exist with another name? I've found the following reformulations of some of these:

```
import Control.Monad (ap)

graph' :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [(a, b)]
graph' = map . ap (,)

liftMaybe' :: (a, Maybe b) -> Maybe (a, b)
liftMaybe' (a, mb) = do
    b <- mb
    return (a, b)

liftMaybe'' :: (a, Maybe b) -> Maybe (a, b)
liftMaybe'' (a, mb) = fmap ((,) a) mb

liftMaybe''' :: (a, Maybe b) -> Maybe (a, b)
liftMaybe''' = uncurry (fmap . (,))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest definition of `liftMaybe` would be

```
import Data.Traversable (sequenceA)

liftMaybe :: (a, Maybe b) -> Maybe (a, b)
liftMaybe = sequenceA
```

The documentation for `sequenceA` can be found here http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Traversable.html.

The general type signature is `sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)`, but in this case `t` is `(,) c` and `f` is `Maybe`.

Also, `partialgraph` could be expressed with `traverse :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)` (which is also from `Data.Traversable`):

```
partialgraph :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [(a, b)]
partialgraph f = mapMaybe $ \x -> traverse f (x, x)
```

or, if you prefer a little more pointlessness:

```
partialgraph f = mapMaybe (traverse f . join (,))
```

EDIT: When I wrote this answer, I didn't realize that the required `Traversable` and `Foldable` instances aren't defined in the GHC 7.6.3 standard library (they are in GHC 7.8 though). Here they are, courtesy of @robx:

```
instance Foldable ((,) a) where
  foldr f y (u, x) = f x y

instance Traversable ((,) a) where
  traverse f (u, x) = (,) u <$> f x
```

Comment: Promising! Is the required `Traversable` instance for `(,) a` defined somewhere? The following works for me:
`instance Foldable ((,) a) where foldr f y (u, x) = f x y` and
`instance Traversable ((,) a) where traverse f (u, x) = (,) u <$> f x`

Comment: @robx: Your suggested edit was correct, I'm not sure why it was declined. I changed it. Anyway, sorry, I didn't notice that the required instance isn't in the stable version of GHC. I was using the GHC 7.8 RC, which has a `(,) a` instance for Traversable in `Data.Traversable`. Your definition is the same as the standard one, so it should work fine.

Answer (score 12):

The simplest approach is probably to use a list comprehension:

```
partialGraph :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [(a, b)]
partialGraph f xs = [(x, fx) | (x, Just fx) <- graph f xs]
```

This takes advantage of the failure semantics of pattern-matching in list comprehensions: if a pattern match fails, then that list element is skipped.<sup>1</sup>

For instance,

```
ghci> partialGraph (\x -> if even x then Just $ x `quot` 2 else Nothing) [1..10]
[(2,1),(4,2),(6,3),(8,4),(10,5)]
```

There doesn't appear to be a `liftSnd :: Functor f => (a, f b) -> f (a,b)` function defined anywhere; `uncurry $ fmap . (,)` is about as concise as you're going to get.

If you define

```
preservingF :: Functor f => (a -> f b) -> a -> f (a, b)
preservingF = liftA2 fmap (,)
```

then you can use this function to define

```
partialGraph :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [(a, b)]
partialGraph = mapMaybe . preservingF
```

which is pretty elegant, although the definition of `preservingF` is a little opaque (especially if you inline it).<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> This is just the (slightly questionable) `fail` (or the perfectly reasonable `mzero`) for the list monad, which simply produces the computation `[]`.

<sup>2</sup> And just as you've been unable to find `liftMaybe`, [I have been unable to find `preservingF` for a long time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2934559/237428).

Comment: I think you're missing an argument in the `preservingF` type signature. If so, it's very similar to `traverse` (if you don't mind an `Applicative` constraint instead of `Functor`): `preservingF f x = traverse f (x, x)`.

Comment: @David: Whoops, fixed, thanks :-)  (That's what I get for not copying from GHCi.)  And thanks for the implementation!

Answer (score 3):

Hoogle returns nothing for `(a,m b) -> m (a,b)`. So I guess the answer is no!
There are a lot of similar functions which I've ended up implementing locally. The closest predefined example I can think of is [sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3asequence):

```
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
```

But you can still hack your way to victory (using Data.Maybe and Control.Arrow):

```
graph f xs = map (second fromJust) $ filter (isJust . snd) $ zip xs $ map f xs
```

Comment: No results for `p a (m b) -> m (p a b)`, or `p a (Maybe b) -> Maybe (p a b)`, either... Too bad.